# Why "String?" does not conform to Equatable

Tags: swift

I create `Observable` class to implement observer pattern in Swift. When a value is changed from old value, this notifies to subscribers, so this generics type should conform to Equatable protocol.
But when a type is `String?` , Xcode raise　`Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'` error.

If I remember correctly, `String` and `String?` conforms to Equatable protocol...why?

```
import UIKit

final class Observable<T: Equatable> {
  typealias ObserverHandler = ((T) -> Void)
  typealias ObserverEntry = (owner: AnyObject, didChange: ObserverHandler)

  var value: T {
    didSet {
      if self.value == oldValue { return }
      self.observers.forEach({ (entry: ObserverEntry) in entry.didChange(self.value) })
    }
  }
  private var observers: [ObserverEntry] = []

  init(_ value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func subscribe(observer: AnyObject, didChange block: @escaping ObserverHandler) {
    let entry: ObserverEntry = (owner: observer, didChange: block)
    observers.append(entry)
  }

  func unsubscribe(observer: AnyObject) {
    let filteredEntries: [ObserverEntry] = observers.filter({ (entry: ObserverEntry) -> Bool in
      return (entry.owner !== observer)
    })
    self.observers = filteredEntries
  }

}

// [!] Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
var foo: Observable<String?> = Observable(nil)
```

Comment: Did you tried with Key Value Observing instead? You can get more info about KVO in this link: https://medium.com/@ericamillado/playing-with-key-value-observing-kvo-swift3-146da9c070a6

Comment: Swift 4.1 update: It is now! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String?` is shorthand for `Optional<String>`. Prior to Swift 4.1, there was no way to make a type conditionally conform to a protocol. E.g. `Optional<T>` should be `Equatable` only where `T` is `Equatable`.

This is called a [conditional conformance](https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/), and in Swift 4.1, `Optional: Equatable where Self.Wrapped: Equatable`.